# How do I view a browser's root certifying authority/certificate hierarchy

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

I am trying to follow the instructions in this link(the first one with 12 reputation points) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Using Firefox 22.0 I am unable to view the certifcate hierarchy, and therefore the root certifying authority for the self-signed site.  **How can I identify the root certifying authority for a site?**  I don't care what browser I use, I just need to identify the root CA.

Firefox's CipherFox Add-On supposedly shows you the certificate hierarchy but when I installed it the add-on never activates(I checked in add-ons that it was enabled though).

(I posted this originally on stackoverflow but the admins told me to post here instead)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly at 22.0, but you go to page info (Tools/Page Info, or ctrl-i) and click on Security / View Certificate / Details. You'll have it in "Certificate hierarchy" - the one at the top is root CA.